# getting answers from multiple answer json

Tags: php, json

This is the json (it can be all from 1 to 10 responses):

```
{"d":[{"__type":"OperatorDataContract:http:\/\/psgi.pts.se\/PTS_Number_Service","Name":"TeliaSonera Sverige AB","Number":"XXXX-XXXXX"},
{"__type":"OperatorDataContract:http:\/\/psgi.pts.se\/PTS_Number_Service","Name":"TeliaSonera Sverige AB","Number":"XXXX-XXXXX"},
{"__type":"OperatorDataContract:http:\/\/psgi.pts.se\/PTS_Number_Service","Name":"Tele2 Sverige AB","Number":"XXXX-XXXXX"}]}
```

I have this when I have 1 response:

```
$str = file_get_contents($apilink);
$data = json_decode($str, true);
$operator = $data['d']['Name'];
```

however if there's multiple answers like in the one ive shown it will just be blank (probably because it finds multiple "Name").
how do you get all the names from the responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get multiple response like this:

```
$data['d'][0]['Name'];
$data['d'][1]['Name'];
$data['d'][2]['Name'];
```

Try this:

```
if (count($data['d']) > 1) {
   foreach($data['d'] as $result){
      $operator[] = $result['Name'];
   }
}
```

Here we loop through the array to obtain multiple names in one single array named $operator.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the foreach loop, here is the sample that will spit out all the names in the json response.

```
$json = '{"d":[{"__type":"OperatorDataContract:http:\/\/psgi.pts.se\/PTS_Number_Service","Name":"TeliaSonera Sverige AB","Number":"XXXX-XXXXX"},
{"__type":"OperatorDataContract:http:\/\/psgi.pts.se\/PTS_Number_Service","Name":"TeliaSonera Sverige AB","Number":"XXXX-XXXXX"},
{"__type":"OperatorDataContract:http:\/\/psgi.pts.se\/PTS_Number_Service","Name":"Tele2 Sverige AB","Number":"XXXX-XXXXX"}]}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$operator = $data['d'];

foreach($operator as $value)
{
    echo $value['Name'].'<br>';

}
```

Hope the above makes sense, also i recommend you read more about [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) so that you can have clear idea on how to play with data in iterative manner